# jQuery Sortable lock item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Is it possible to lock an item in a Sortable list once it's been dropped?

Basically, I have a sortable list [OBJECT] that the user is supposed to place the objects into steps. The steps are static/not moveable. Like this:

[Step 1] [OBJECT 1]

[Step 2] [OBJECT 2]

[Step 3] [OBJECT 3]

[Step 4] [OBJECT 4]

So lets say I drag object 1 to step 3:

[Step 1] [OBJECT 2]

[Step 2] [OBJECT 3]

**[Step 3] [OBJECT 1]**

[Step 4] [OBJECT 4]

Now any object that's dragged SHOULD NOT change the position of [OBJECT 1]  because it needs to stay at step 3.

Is it possible to lock it?

Comment: What's the criteria for locking an item? Is it just after the first time it's moved/dropped it gets locked?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly it.

Comment: What if in your example [OBJECT 4] is dragged in step2? I cannot see what you are expecting

Comment: If you were to drag 4 to 2... object 3 would move down to step4.

Comment: So if its what you are looking for, lavrik answer is correct. But as i read: "SHOULD NOT change the position of [OBJECT 1] because it needs to stay at step 3."   so???

Comment: This illustrate lavrik's answer: http://jsfiddle.net/nvTjC/

Comment: @roasted - if I understand the OP correctly, once an item is moved it should be disabled. Your fiddle doesn't do that.

Comment: Yes, it SHOULD NOT change the position. Lavrik's answer isn't what I'm looking for because all it does is lock an item so that it can't be dragged...

Comment: @lavrik it was just to illustrate the cancel option

Comment: Read my 2-nd comment to my answer. This can help. Just implement the swap before item is droped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for me to achieve this was to use drag & drop. I explain more about what I did here: [jQuery Drag & drop- reorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980047/jquery-drag-drop-reorder/16022314#16022314)

Answer (score 0):

May be 'cancel' option can help ypu.

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable( "option", "cancel", "a,button" );
```

Check [this link](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel)

Comment: This just cancel sortable on selected element, this doesn't fix position

Comment: Yes. Sorry, misunderstood the sample. And what if make each step as separate list. Connect them and when you need to lock an item just disable\remove a sortable at all at the item to lock. The only issue in this case is to swap items between lists. But i think hadnling some event can help manually swap items to ensure each list contains only one element at a time.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/byCgp/ - this sample swaps only neighborhoods. So you can disable any of list - ul - and continue movement between other lists. The sample is only a concept it doesn't cover all the move cases.